# How to make a gradient of View Border color?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-animation

```
 private let containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        var gradientBorderLayer: CAGradientLayer?
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        view.layer.borderWidth = 1
        gradientBorderLayer = view.getGradientWithBorderLayer(with: .gradientColorFirst, .gradientColorSecond)
        view.layer.addSublayer(gradientBorderLayer ?? CAGradientLayer())
        return view
    }()

 func getGradientWithBorderLayer(with firstColor: UIColor, _ secondColor: UIColor) -> CAGradientLayer {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: bounds.size)
        gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.1)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.1)

        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: shapeLayer.lineWidth, dy: shapeLayer.lineWidth), cornerRadius: layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer

        return gradientLayer
    }
```

I am trying to make view border color like this. But instead of the gradient color, the border color of the view looks black. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @matt the gradient is derived from the change in `x` value, not `y`.

Comment: check this and make sure that it contain width and height : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558474/rounded-gradient-border-on-uibutton

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a lot of context so what I've done is encapsulated all of the functionality into a subclassed `UIView` so you can better understand how the gradient layer works. It's hard to pinpoint the problem you encountered because of the missing context. I don't know if variables were simply out of scope, if they weren't available to the function when they were read, or something else. I didn't actually change anything of significance from your code, which means you have the concept down. Your problem appears to just be implementation.

You can copy and paste this into an Xcode Playground (with live views enabled by going to **Editor > Live View**) to see it in action.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let h = rect.height
        let w = rect.width
        
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame =  CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: w, height: h))
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: w, height: h), cornerRadius: 20).cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer
        
        layer.cornerRadius = 20
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}

class Preview: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
        
        let x = CustomView()
        x.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        x.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(x)
        x.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        x.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        x.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 96).isActive = true
        x.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 96).isActive = true
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = Preview()
```